# Why can't I convert a string "20L" to Long in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can assign 10L to a long `var aa`.

Now I hope to convert a string bb="20L" to a long , but I get the error *My Error: For input string: "20L"* , why?

```
 val aa=10L 
 val bb="20L"

 try{
     val cc=bb.toLong()
 }catch (e:Exception){
    logError("My Error: "+e.message?:" None")
 }
```

**Added Content**

I hope to store a long value to key `"AutoRestoreID"`, which one is correct between `android:defaultValue="-1"` and `android:defaultValue="-1L"` ?

And more, I don't know if I can only store a string value to the key `"AutoRestoreID"` when I use `ListPreference`, could you tell me?

```
<ListPreference
   android:key="AutoRestoreID"
   android:defaultValue="-1"              
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried *without* the `L`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string "`20L`" is not a valid number (the string "`20`" would be). The "`L`" helps the compiler to determine the type of the numeric literal (otherwise it might be an `Int` instead of a `Long`), but that's a *compiler* (and therefore Kotlin syntax) feature, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Sorry I haven't done much Android development, but I'd try the plain "`-1`" and see what happens (either it will work or it will throw an Exception, and hopefully that help figure out what to do next)